# How to delete previous states of store in ngrx?

Tags: angular, store, ngrx

As I know the store is a list of states, each state has direct access to his previous or next state. this list is saved in applications memory, if I have a huge amount of data and each state is too big to be saved in every state. How can I permanently delete old store objects to avoid overstock of memory?

at this moment my code looks like this:

```
export const REDUCERS = {
    login: loginReducer,
    register: registerReducer,
    profile: profileReducer,
    company: companyReducer,
    balance: balanceReducer
}
const SdkReducer = compose(storeLogger(), combineReducers)(REDUCERS);

export function reducer(state: any, action: any) {
    if(action.type === 'RESET_STORE'){
        return undefined;
    }

    return SdkReducer(state, action);
}
```

When 'RESET_STORE' is called root reducer returns 'udefined', But, as I know, there is still saved the old state of the store, which contains old data. I want to delete it permanently. To free some memory.

Comment: garbage collection is handled by browsers in the web world.  Your job as a web app dev is to make sure you don't do things that prevents the browser from garbage collecting, like holding onto references to old data so that your browser can't collect it.  In this case, you're leaning on a framework to do that for you in some places, and you need to hope they did it right, or go through there code and figure out what's going on if you think they messed up.  ngrx is pretty good, they don't actually hold all previous state, this is a mischaracterization of what it does.

Comment: Thanks Bryan again. Your explanation helped me to understand how old states are saved.

Answer (score 2):

```
const initialState = appReducer({}, {})

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
 if (action.type === 'RESET_STORE') {
   state = initialState
 }
 return appReducer(state, action)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. But as i know this will only reset current state, old data still will be saved in memory. I want to delete unnecessary data, not only reset current state.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do that at all. It's done by the garbage collector of the browser.

Just make sure you don't hold a reference to your previous states somewhere.

For example if you create a middleware which push every previous state into an array, they'll never be cleaned and your memory consumption will increase over time without decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of ngrx is a little off.  ngrx doesn't actually hold onto all previous state.  The idea behind ngrx is that if you do it right, the same set of actions and payloads should always produce the same application state, in this sense, the record of actions and payloads is a complete history of your app state at each point in time.

You have no need to do what you're describing.  If you're having memory issues, you're probably inadverdently creating a leak somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for clear response. This helped me a lot.